# JavaScript alert doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to built a select option menu. If the user chooses the first (default) option, the alert window should be shown, but it isn't shown. Need help, thanks!

Here is my html code

```
    <select name="sets" id ="selectset">
        <option value="General">Select Set</option>
        <option value="The Happy Couple">Ceremony</option>
        <option value="Ceremony">Ceremony</option>
        <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
        <option value="Garden">Garden</option>
        <option value="Longname">This is max length</option>
      </select>
     <input type="button" class="form_button" id="movetoset" value="  Move Marked to Set">
```

Here is my javascript code

```
    $('#movetoset').click(function() {      

              if(document.getElementById("selectset").value == "General"){
                  alert("Please choose a set");
              }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I made a fiddle and everything.

Comment: My goodness, Tony, un ***`accept`*** able

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why aren't you using jQuery for getting the value of the select as well?

http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/CUGva/

Answer (score 0):

change html code to

```
<input type="button" class="form_button" onclick="checkFunct()" id="movetoset" value="  Move Marked to Set">
```

and add javascript

```
function checkFunct() {
    if(document.getElementById("selectset").value == "General"){
              alert("Please choose a set");
          }
  }
```

Comment: why should you write onsubmit event here. It will not do anything here is the input type is button not submit

Comment: Why make it *less* jQuery-y? (And what *is* `item` for?)

Comment: Why use jquery when you don't have to. I love Jquery, but don't use it everywhere. I think I should remove item, shouldn't I... (: removed

Comment: Because OP was already using it, it's shorter, and there are actually reasons to prefer unobtrusive JavaScript.

Comment: Even assuming it's a good idea to change the whole thing and remove jQuery, what was wrong with the code in the question? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the JavaScript code you posted is either:

- In the document ready (or onload) handler, and/or
- After the HTML in the page source

Otherwise when you try to select the button by its ID the button element won't have been parsed yet so it won't be found and no click handler will be attached.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
   // other document ready processing (if any) here

   $('#movetoset').click(function() {
      if($("#selectset").val() == "General"){
         alert("Please choose a set");
      }
   }

   // other document ready processing (if any) here
});
```

(Noting that `$(function() {});` is short-hand for `$(document).ready(function(){});`)

And as long as you're using jQuery, why not use its `.val()` function?